# How to show video player in list with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a screen like the home page on Instagram. My problem is when I scroll the list or the list gets bigger, the app got laggy on the scroll and got a memory issue.
This is my Listview.builder:

```
ListView.builder(
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: controller.items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return HomeItem(
                       index: index,
                       url: 'video_url',
                       token: controller.token);
                      },)
```

And This is HomeItem:

```
class HomeItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String token;
  final String url;

  const HomeItem(
      {super.key, required this.index, required this.url, required this.token});

  @override
  State<HomeItem> createState() => _HomeItemState();
}

class _HomeItemState extends State<HomeItem> {
  int get index => widget.index;

  String get url => widget.url;

  String get token => widget.token;
  late CachedVideoPlayerController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeController() async {
    _controller = CachedVideoPlayerController.network(
        '$baseUrlForGetFiles/${widget.url}',
        httpHeaders: {'Authorization': "Bearer $token"});
    await _controller?.initialize().then((_) async {
      _controller?.setLooping(true);
      await _controller?.play();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: _controller?.value.size.width,
              height: _controller?.value.size.height,
              child: CachedVideoPlayer(_controller!),
            )));
  }
}
```

I use [cached_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_video_player/) plugin for handling cache videos.

So, I have 2 questions: How to show videos without memory issues and lag in Listview? And Is using the cached_video_player plugin good for caching videos?